# What plans exist for another future international space station after the ISS is retired, and what stage of development are the plans at?

Tags: iss, crewed-spaceflight, space-station, research

I've been scouring the internet to try to find information on this. Unfortunately most of what I've found has indicated that there are currently no plans for another international alliance project in space. I was wondering if anyone has managed to find information about future orbital manned space stations?

Given the complexity of these projects, I understand that it would take a long time to design and construct the components for a new station, which really saddens me as it implies that its allowed the continual inhabitation of space by man for over 15 years.

I feel that it really is a great symbol of union on Earth, and a healthy reminder of what we can do when we work together as one species. It'd be a huge shame to lose such an asset, with no vision for further discoveries/experiments of this unique type.

I guess maybe the general public has lost interest in space since the moon landings. I do find it incredibly frustrating that America decides to spend more money on [its military every year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_military_expenditures) than has been spent throughout [NASA's total history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budget_of_NASA). Obviously, some of the military research does benefit humanities knowledge and understanding (e.g. NIF), but I cant help but imagine what the world would be like if the leaders of nations focused their efforts on advancing together instead of developing ever more destructive weapons and focusing on killing each other.

I'd love to hear the thoughts of others on how to get people to wake up and realise people across the world are not all that different. I'm adamant that international projects like the ISS (besides providing vast improvements to our technologies and basic understanding of science) are an incredible way to help people see how insignificant their squabbles are in the infinity of the cosmos.

Comment: There are many plans, could you please [edit] to clarify what you mean with _serious_ and do they have to be _international_? There's the Chinese Tiangong-2 which is expected to launch this year, Russia has been publicly contemplating its own successor to the ISS just as the west applied pressure following the Crimea crisis (coincidence?), there's several private ventures with various _plans_,... Most of your question seems to be a superfluous invitation to conjecture and open discussion, which is not what we do here as a Q&A site. See [Ask]. Thanks!

Comment: See e.g. [Wikipedia on Space station - Future developments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_station#Future_developments). And for one biiiig conjecture, see Keck Institute's lecture: [Building the First Spaceport in Low Earth Orbit](http://www.kiss.caltech.edu/new_website/lectures/Blincow_Lecture_2016.html).

Answer (score 4):

The Russians have a plan (that is slowly disappearing as the oil crunch kills their budgets) to detach the future OM and MLM modules (Nauka) and all that go with it as a standalone station once the ISS is retired (aka Splashed into the Pacific). Who knows if that will happen. The Russians are not in great shape financially, but they could succeed.

Bigelow has serious plans for a commercial research station made out of inflatables. They have mostly been waiting for commercial crew to happen. They have launched two subscale modules (Genesis I and II). They have BEAM launching on CRS-8 in the Dragon's unpressurized trunk to be berthed to Node 3 and stay on the station for 2 years. This will prove the technology to NASA even further, and get Bigelow serious experience.

They need a heavy lifter to launch their main/big module (BA-330), which is Falcon Heavy and is always just a few months away from first launch. They need a crew vehicle other than Soyuz to get there, and have contracts with Boeing (CST-100/Starliner) and SpaceX (Dragon V2/Crew). They just need those other vendors to deliver.

Other than that, the US has no serious plans that are funded and look real right now.

China is planning on Tiangong, in a model similar to Mir in the near future.